# How can i sort an laravel eloquent query by one-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, sorting

I have a products table, and every product can have many inventory.
A query result that i want to achieve is sorting products by price field in inventory table.

```
$products = Product::with(['inventories' => function($query){
    $query->where('count', '>', 0)->orderBy('id');
}])->paginate(16);
return $products;
```

The result is:

```
data: [
{
    id: 1,
    brand_id: 3,
    category_id: 5,
    title: "فشارسنج عقربه ای و گوشی پزشکی هانسون مدل وکتو",
    body: null,
    sales: "2",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5ca0b4607158f.jpg",
    post_on: "15",
    fast_shipping_cost: "50000",
    weight: "300",
    created_at: "2019-04-21 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-21 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 1,
          product_id: 1,
          count: "10",          
          price: "75000",
          expiration_date: null
      }
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    brand_id: 3,
    category_id: 5,
    title: "فشارسنج دیجیتال مدیسانا مدل BU 550 Connect",
    body: null,
    sales: "10",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5cb70c11cfaf0.jpg",
    post_on: "20",
    fast_shipping_cost: null,
    weight: "250",
    created_at: "2019-04-22 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-22 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 2,
          product_id: 2,
          count: "5",          
          price: "150000",
          expiration_date: null
      },
      {
          id: 4,
          product_id: 2,
          count: "7",          
          price: "155000",
          expiration_date: null
      }
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    brand_id: 1,
    category_id: 6,
    title: "سوزن تست قند خون تی دی-تین بسته 100 عددی",
    body: null,
    sales: "5",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5cbafe568518c.jpg",
    post_on: null,
    fast_shipping_cost: null,
    weight: "150",
    created_at: "2019-04-23 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-23 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 3,
          product_id: 3,
          count: "4",          
          price: "98000",
          expiration_date: null
      }
    ]
}
],
```

Sort on `$query->where('count', '>', 0)->sortBy('price')` only do a sort in inventories i want this sort apply on products.
I want the result to be like this:
Sort by inventory price, and has only one inventory in result.
First 150000 then 98000 and then 50000

```
data: [
{
    id: 2,
    brand_id: 3,
    category_id: 5,
    title: "فشارسنج دیجیتال مدیسانا مدل BU 550 Connect",
    body: null,
    sales: "10",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5cb70c11cfaf0.jpg",
    post_on: "20",
    fast_shipping_cost: null,
    weight: "250",
    created_at: "2019-04-22 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-22 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 2,
          product_id: 2,
          count: "5",          
          price: "150000",
          expiration_date: null
      },    
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    brand_id: 1,
    category_id: 6,
    title: "سوزن تست قند خون تی دی-تین بسته 100 عددی",
    body: null,
    sales: "5",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5cbafe568518c.jpg",
    post_on: null,
    fast_shipping_cost: null,
    weight: "150",
    created_at: "2019-04-23 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-23 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 3,
          product_id: 3,
          count: "4",          
          price: "98000",
          expiration_date: null
      }
    ]
}
{
    id: 1,
    brand_id: 3,
    category_id: 5,
    title: "فشارسنج عقربه ای و گوشی پزشکی هانسون مدل وکتو",
    body: null,
    sales: "2",
    image: "images/product/product-image-index-5ca0b4607158f.jpg",
    post_on: "15",
    fast_shipping_cost: "50000",
    weight: "300",
    created_at: "2019-04-21 15:27:58",
    updated_at: "2019-04-21 15:27:58",
    deleted_at: null,
    inventories: [
      {
          id: 1,
          product_id: 1,
          count: "10",          
          price: "75000",
          expiration_date: null
      }
    ]
},
],
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem:
First off all add a hasOne relation to Product model:

```
public function latestInventory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Inventory::class);
}
```

Then in ProductController:

```
$products = Product::with(['latestInventory' => function($query) {
    $query->where('count', '>', 0)->orderBy('id');
}]);
$products = $products->get();
$products = $products->sortBy('latestInventory.price')->paginate(16);

return $products->values()->toArray();
```

For Paginate the collection :
In ASP (AppServiceProvider.php) on boot method:

```
Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]
        );
    });
```

In app/Support/Collection.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Support;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection as BaseCollection;
class Collection extends BaseCollection
{
    public function paginate($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page')
    {
        $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
            $total ?: $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            [
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'pageName' => $pageName,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on my tables, and to achieve this I used `join` instead of a `with` on the model, so please try this approach:

```
$products = Product::join('inventories as i', 'products.id', '=', 'i.product_id')
            ->where('i.count', '>', 0)
            ->orderBy('i.price') // default is asc order, but as a second parameter you can use desc if you need to.
            ->paginate(16);
```

-- EDIT

```
$products = Product::with('inventories')->join('inventories as i', 'products.id', '=', 'i.product_id')
            ->where('i.count', '>', 0)
            ->orderBy('i.price') // default is asc order, but as a second parameter you can use desc if you need to.
            ->groupBy('products.id')
            ->paginate(16);
```

Comment: Thanks, but output it not right.  I have only three products but in result show me four products, the product that has two inventories come in result twice, if it has 10 inventories it repeat that product 10 times, and sort not work at all if only one product has more than one inventories.

Comment: Yes, so I showed you the way to sort the products based on your conditions, I have edited my answer which you can try, I believe it will solve your issue.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #14 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'anti-diabetes-db.i.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `inventories` as `i` on `products`.`id` = `i`.`product_id` where `i`.`count` > 0 and `products`.`deleted_at` is null group by `products`.`id` order by `i`.`price` asc limit 16 offset 0) ◀"

Comment: You cannot group by the inventory id, that will again give you duplicate results if it works out with the columns that you will select. I showed you to group them by the `products.id`.

Comment: I group by `products.id` same as your code but it has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$products = Product::with(['inventories' => function($query){
    $query->where('count', '>', 0)->orderBy('id');
}])->join('inventories','product.id','=','inventories.product_id')
->select('product.*)->orderBy('inventories.price')
->paginate(16);
return $products;
```

Currently there is no function in Eloquent to sort by relation, you have to perform a join to sort by relation. Also don't forget to add select('product.*) when joining, else there are some anomaly issues in laravel which replaces the primary id with the joining table id.